# need to clean file via SED or GREP

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I have these files

- `NotRequired.txt`    (having lines which need to be remove)
- `Need2CleanSED.txt`  (big file , need to clean)
- `Need2CleanGRP.txt`  (big file , need to clean)

content:

```
more NotRequired.txt
[abc-xyz_pqr-pe2_123]
[lon-abc-tkt_1202]
[wat-7600-1_414]
[indo-pak_isu-5_761]
```

I am reading above file and want to remove lines from `Need2Clean???.txt`, trying via SED and GREP but no success.

```
myFile="NotRequired.txt"

while IFS= read -r HKline

do

  sed -i '/$HKline/d' Need2CleanSED.txt

done < "$myFile"


myFile="NotRequired.txt"

while IFS= read -r HKline

do

  grep -vE \"$HKline\" Need2CleanGRP.txt > Need2CleanGRP.txt

done < "$myFile"
```

Looks as if the Variable and characters [] making some problem.

Comment: You have to use double quotes to dereference variables: `sed -i "/$HKline/d" Need2CleanSED.txt`.

Answer (score 3):

What you're doing is extremely inefficient and error prone. Just do this:

```
grep -vF -f NotRequired.txt Need2CleanGRP.txt > tmp &&
mv tmp Need2CleanGRP.txt
```

Thanks to `grep -F` the above treats each line of NotRequired.txt as a string rather than a regexp so you don't have to worry about escaping RE metachars like `[` and you don't need to wrap it in a shell loop - that one command will remove all undesirable lines in one execution of `grep`.

Never do `command file > file` btw as the shell might decide to execute the `> file` first and so empty `file` before `command` gets a chance to read it! Always do `command file > tmp && mv tmp file` instead.

Comment: Thanks for advice, just want to be clear, me seeing 2 lines, if these are really 2 lines, what is meaning of && in first line. If its whole one line command then its Okay (second line will execute after the first). && = AND operator

Comment: The `&&` means `execute the 2nd command only if the first one succeeds`. Without that if the `grep` failed then the `mv` would be replacing your `Need2CleanGRP.txt` file with an empty `tmp` file.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is correct.  The `[...]` construct looks for any characters in that set, so you have to preface ("escape") them with `\`.  The easiest way is to do that in your original file:

```
sed -i -e 's:\[:\\[:' -e 's:\]:\\]:' "${myFile}"
```

If you don't like that, you can probably put the `sed` command in where you're directing the file in:

```
done < replace.txt|sed -e 's:\[:\\[:' -e 's:\]:\\]:'
```

Finally, you can use sed on each `HKline` variable:

```
HKline=$( echo $HKline | sed -e 's:\[:\\[:' -e 's:\]:\\]:' )
```

Comment: Thanks Jack/Bummi...its resolved (i have edited my original file NotRequired.txt with \\[abc-xyz_pqr-pe2_123]  (added slash \ in each line as as first character)  and       sed -i -e "/$HKline/d" Need2CleanSED.txt

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/29613304/1745001 for some of the other chars and strings you also need to be careful of with this approach and also be wary of any globbing chars or spaces.

Answer (score 0):

try gnu sed:

```
sed -Ez 's/\n/\|/g;s!\[!\\[!g;s!\]!\\]!g; s!(.*).!/\1/d!' NotRequired.txt| sed -Ef - Need2CleanSED.txt
```

Two sed process are chained into one by shell pipe
`NotRequired.txt` is 'slurped' by `sed -z`  all at once and substituted its `\n` and `[` meta-char with `|` and `\[` respectively of which the 2nd process uses it as regex script for the input file, ie. Need2CleanSED.txt. 1st process output;

```
/\[abc-xyz_pqr-pe2_123\]|\[lon-abc-tkt_1202\]|\[wat-7600-1_414\]|\[indo-pak_isu-5_761\]/d
```

add `-u` ie. unbuffered, option to evade from batch process, sort of direct i/o

Comment: can you please explain above and reply to specific question using these files name (NotRequired.txt , Need2CleanSED.txt) will help in future for other users too.

Comment: Thanks Abdan, just one clarification, if NotRequired.txt having 30000+ lines, similar pattern, will handle , will execute successfully ? or need help from : xargs command

Comment: GNU sed version 4.2.1 ,, sed: invalid option -- 'z'   (I USED => sed -Ezu rest is same as you mentioned in very first line)